# Why am I getting errors while adding launcher icon in flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

So, I am trying change the default flutter launcher icon with my one. I am using the `flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2` from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons).
The code in pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  hexcolor: ^2.0.5
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  flutter_neumorphic: ^3.2.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.4
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  android: true
  ios: true
```

But when I am running `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main`, I am getting error saying:

```
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
     FLUTTER LAUNCHER ICONS (v0.9.1)
  ════════════════════════════════════════════


✓ Successfully generated launcher icons
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)

^

#0      int._handleFormatError (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:129:7)
#1      int.parse (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:55:14)
#2      minSdk (package:flutter_launcher_icons/android.dart:309:18)
#3      createIconsFromConfig (package:flutter_launcher_icons/main.dart:94:47)
#4      createIconsFromArguments (package:flutter_launcher_icons/main.dart:60:7)
#5      main (file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.9.2/bin/main.dart:6:26)
#6      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:295:32)
#7      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
pub finished with exit code 255
```

And the Icon doesn't change.

## What probably the problem?

=> I mean, coz it worked many times before...

Comment: does remove command works?

Comment: try version `0.9.2`. It will not fix it, but it might give a better error?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Go to `android/app/build.gradle` and change the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to integer values.

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName flutterVersionName
```

Then do the rest, i.e.

```
pub.get -> flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

Comment: For people out there who using flutter_launcher_icons ^0.9.2 can also try making minSdkVersion to 16.  It worked then.

Comment: This works! But why does it need to be done when using this package?

Answer (score 8):

Another way to fix the issue, which also worked for me.

### About

This error is mainly caused due to the `android: true`, when I tried after following many articles by using

**(pubspec.yaml)**

```
flutter_icons:
  image_path: "images/icon.png" 
  android: false
  ios: true
```

it worked only for ios, after which I got a recommendation code to be used for ios. I added.

```
flutter_icons:
  image_path: "images/icon.png" 
  android: false
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true  //recommendation added
```

### Final Step

***(Optional)***

> mistakes are done by me

Just check if you have written any extra code in the same file because I faced a lot of trouble due to my extra code in the file `build.gradle`.This line is used to fetch the value of `flutter.minSdkVersion` from the `android\local.properties` file.

```
def flutterminSdkVersion = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion')
```

**(android\app\build.gradle)**

```
    minSdkVersion 16 
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
```

And then running the usual code

```
flutter pub get 
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

and I got the output

```
 ════════════════════════════════════════════
     FLUTTER LAUNCHER ICONS (v0.9.1)
  ════════════════════════════════════════════

• Creating default icons Android
• Overwriting the default Android launcher icon with a new icon
• Overwriting default iOS launcher icon with new icon

✓ Successfully generated launcher icons
```

ultimately the above code solves the issue, I hope anyone can get help from this and save his/her valuable time.

Attaching some sources, which helped me in the final verdict.

https://issueexplorer.com/issue/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/301
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues/88

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem and found a solution

**1.Add dependancy as below** [pubspec.yaml]

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2  // add lib as here
```

**2. add below line** [pubspec.yaml]

```
flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/launcher_icon.png"
  android: true
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
```

**3.Open `local.properties` file and add below line** [android\local.properties]

```
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
```

**4.Now go to `app/build.gradle` file and add this if not present:** [app level > build.gradle]

```
def flutterMinSdkVersion = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion')
if (flutterMinSdkVersion == null) {
    flutterMinSdkVersion = flutter.minSdkVersion.toString()
}
```

**5.Then go to `defaultConfig` in `build.gradle`** [go to below same file]

replace this line >  `minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion`

with this > `minSdkVersion flutterMinSdkVersion`

**6. go to `build.gradle` and save**

**7. go to `local.properties` and save**

**8. go to android studio and run below**

```
flutter pub get 
    
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

**It will work :) !**

Answer (score 3):

Solved with replacing this line (android/app/build.gradle)
flutter_launcher_icons does not work below minSdjVersion 21

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks man, actually flutter_launcher_icons does not work below minSdjVersion 21

Answer (score 3):

I happen to notice https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons_maker   - which worked 1st go.
(None of the solutions here worked for me during many hours of trying - and breaking stuff - that took even more time to fix :( ).

Remove the original with `flutter pub remove flutter_launcher_icons`  then follow the instructions and be happy.

Comment: it was simply a ```flutter clean```.

Comment: I tried flutter clean etc. but that dint fix it for me.

Answer (score 2):

For Upcoming Users, here a simple fix:
If you don't have a **`flutter.minSdkVersion`** property, then add it to local.properties file:

```
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
```

After That go to app/build.gradle file and add this if not present:

```
def flutterMinSdkVersion = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion')
if (flutterMinSdkVersion == null) {
    flutterMinSdkVersion = flutter.minSdkVersion.toString()
}
```

Then in default config: edit it like this:

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example'
        minSdkVersion flutterMinSdkVersion.toString()
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Then run the flutter launcher icon command:

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to android/app/build.gradle and change the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to integer values.

minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName flutterVersionName

Then do the rest, i.e.

flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main

Answer (score 1):

In my case I
changed

```
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
```

to

```
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.1
```

and that's be fix.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and it worked by changing the minsdk, targetsdk, and compilesdk then I deleted the package then added it again through this code line:

```
flutter pub add flutter_launcher_icons
```

of course, I did so while not deleting this code line in pubspec.yaml file:

```
flutter_icons:
 image_path: assets/food-delivery_app_icon.png
 android: true
 ios: true
```

But the weird thing I found as well is that it wrote in the success message the 0.9.1 version of the package not the 0.9.2 ver as the code line to add the package, gets the latest version of the package

[Evidence of What I Said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ7X7.jpg)